# Django - Error during inporting Excel csv file with Pandas

Tags: django, pandas, csv

I am having error on this code which is for csv importing data into the database using Django.
This is the error.
Many thanks for your help

MultiValueDictKeyError at /countyImportFromExcelPd/
'countryList'

```
#model.py

### For the list of the country
class Country(models.Model):
    ### country_di = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    country_iso2 = models.CharField(verbose_name='Country ISO 2 codes', max_length=4, null=True, blank=False)
    country_iso3 = models.CharField(verbose_name='Country ISO 3 codes', max_length=4, null=True, blank=False)
    country_name_EN = models.CharField(verbose_name='English', max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    country_name_FR = models.CharField(verbose_name='Francais', max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    country_name_DE = models.CharField(verbose_name='Desch', max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    country_name_ES = models.CharField(verbose_name='Espagnol', max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    country_comment = models.CharField(verbose_name='Comments', max_length=1024, null=False, blank=True, help_text='Coments on the payment')
    country_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)


#View.py

def countyImportFromExcelPd(request): 

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['countryList']:      
        countryList = request.FILES['countryList']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(countryList.name, countryList)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)              
        empexceldata = pd.read_excel(filename)        
        dbframe = empexceldata
        for dbframe in dbframe.itertuples():
            obj = Country.objects.create(country_iso2=dbframe.country_iso2, country_iso3=dbframe.country_iso3,
                                            country_name_EN=dbframe.country_name_EN, country_name_FR=dbframe.country_name_FR, country_name_DE=dbframe.country_name_DE, country_name_ES=dbframe.country_name_ES,
                                            country_comment=dbframe.country_comment )           
            obj.save()
        return render(request, 'students_management_app/country-import.html', {
            'uploaded_file_url': uploaded_file_url
        })   
    return render(request, 'country-import.html',{})

# url.py
path('countyImportFromExcelPd/', views.countyImportFromExcelPd, name='county-import-ExcelPd'),
```